# Linux : Replace key-value pair, value contains file path

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a config file that looks like this

```
client {
keyTab="/home/path"
}
```

I want to change the keyTab key value based on current directory. My script goes like this

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
sed -c -i "s/\(keyTab\s*=\s*\).*$/\1NEWPATH/" file.cfg
```

When i run this script the `"/home/path"` is replaced by `NEWPATH`. However when i change the sed to

```
sed -c -i "s#^\(keyTab\s*=\s*\).*$#\1NEW/PATH#' file.cfg
```

then nothing happens. I am expecting the value to change to `NEW/PATH`. Eventually my aim is to replace the value in config with contents of `DIR` variable.

Please s(h)ed some light on how to make sed work in this case.

===========================================================

**Update** : After taking major hints from the answers provided below i was able to get it working. Following line does exactly what i want..

```
sed -i 's|\(keyTab\s*=\).*|\1"'"$DIR"'"|' file.conf
```

Comment: Upvote for the pun at the end... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

***sed*** approach:

```
DIR="$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
sed -i 's#^\(keyTab\s*=\).*#\1"'"$DIR"'"#' file.cfg
```

Comment: hey! i tried this..does not change the value at all and neither gives any error ..i am running these commands in a bash script..

Comment: what does `echo $DIR` return?

Comment: `'/home/ayushm/repos/schema/firm-schema/target/scripts/dev'`

Comment: is the `-` character in path causing any issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how my sed is working:

`sed -i 's/^\(keyTab=\).*/\1NEW\/PATH/' test.conf`